Who is considered a Harbi?
Is a Harbi a person who's at war with Muslims? Or does merely living in a non Muslim state with no treaty make one a Harbi?
If a person did not do anything to harm the Muslims can he be considered a Harbi?

Please ask one indivisible question per post and also search the site for existing answers which cover your inquiries. Your post consisted of multiple questions, some of which had already been answered before hand, see Does islam allow killing or enslaving civilians in war?. I have now focused it to one question.

A Harbi is defined as follows:

أهل الحرب أو الحربيون: هم غير المسلمين الذين لم يدخلوا في عقد الذمة، ولا يتمتعون بأمان المسلمين ولا عهدهم
The Harbis are non-Muslims who have not entered a contract of Dhimmah, and have not been granted sanctuary by the Muslims, and do not have any treaty with them
— Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah

A disbeliever with a treaty can be either one of the following:

Dhimmi: A disbeliever with a special type of permanent treaty whereby he becomes a citizen of the Dar al-Islam, agrees to be subjected to Islamic laws and to pay annual Jizyah.

Musta’min: A disbeliever who has been granted sanctuary by a Muslim. Especially one who visits the Dar al-Islam temporarily on assurance of safety.

Mu‘aahid: A disbeliever with whom a ceasefire pact is made for a temporary duration.


A Harbi is anyone who is a kafir and is not among the above categories - i.e. he does have not any form of treaty with the Muslims. In the absence of a treaty war exists, it is the default status and does not have to be declared. There isn't any category of disbelievers with whom the Muslims do not have any treaty and are also not at war:

كان المشركون على منزلتين من النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم والمؤمنين، كانوا مشركي أهل حرب يقاتلهم ويقاتلونه، ومشركي أهل عهد لا يقاتلهم ولا يقاتلونه
The pagans were of two kinds as regards their relationship to the Prophet (ﷺ) and the Believers. Some of them were those with whom the Prophet (ﷺ) was at war and used to fight against, and they used to fight him; the others were those with whom the Prophet (ﷺ) made a treaty, and neither did the Prophet (ﷺ) fight them, nor did they fight him.
— Bukhari

The Quran and Sunnah talk about fighting all the disbelievers in general and make an exception for those with a treaty.

قاتلوا الذين لا يؤمنون بالله ولا باليوم الآخر ولا يحرمون ما حرم الله ورسوله ولا يدينون دين الحق من الذين أوتوا الكتاب حتى يعطوا الجزية عن يد وهم صاغرون
Fight those who do not believe in Allah or in the Last Day and who do not consider unlawful what Allah and His Messenger have made unlawful and who do not adopt the religion of truth from those who were given the Scripture - [fight] until they give the jizyah willingly while they are humbled.
— Quran 9:29


إلا الذين عاهدتم من المشركين ثم لم ينقصوكم شيئا ولم يظاهروا عليكم أحدا فأتموا إليهم عهدهم إلى مدتهم
Excepted are those with whom you made a treaty among the polytheists and then they have not been deficient toward you in anything or supported anyone against you; so complete for them their treaty until their term [has ended].
— Quran 9:4


أمرت أن أقاتل الناس حتى يشهدوا أن لا إله إلا الله وأن محمدا رسول الله، ويقيموا الصلاة، ويؤتوا الزكاة، فإذا فعلوا ذلك عصموا مني دماءهم وأموالهم إلا بحق الإسلام، وحسابهم على الله
I have been ordered (by Allah) to fight against the people until they testify that none has the right to be worshipped but Allah and that Muhammad is Allah's Messenger (ﷺ), and offer the prayers perfectly and give the obligatory charity, so if they perform that, then they save their lives and property from me except for Islamic laws and then their reckoning (accounts) will be done by Allah.
— Bukhari


من قتل معاهدا لم يرح رائحة الجنة، وإن ريحها توجد من مسيرة أربعين عاما
Whoever killed a person having a treaty with the Muslims, shall not smell the smell of Paradise though its smell is perceived from a distance of forty years.
— Bukhari

Those who do not qualify for an exception fall under the default rule of war. Their property can be taken away without their consent and they can be enslaved or ransomed. They can also be executed if they fought or are considered capable of fighting.
Two factors make one a Harbi :

Kufr: That is refusing to accept Islam. A Harbi who accepted Islam, even if after capture, can not be executed. One who can prove that he had accepted Islam before capture can not be harmed at all.

Lack of a treaty or breach of treaty: This can be done even by remaining passive as it is tacit approval of the actions of one's faction or leaders. However a Harbi may dissociate himself from his faction and approach the Muslims to make a treaty of Dhimmah for himself - before being captured. If he does not then the status of his faction applies to him:

واتقوا فتنة لا تصيبن الذين ظلموا منكم خاصة واعلموا أن الله شديد العقاب
And fear a trial which will not strike those who have wronged among you exclusively, and know that Allah is severe in penalty.
— Quran 8:25




Ref:

وأباح دم الكافر وماله إلا بأن يؤدي الجزية أو يستأمن إلى مدة
And Allah has made the blood and property of a disbeliever lawful except when he pays Jizya or is given sanctuary for a limited period of time
— Kitab al-Umm

